# How should I reroll a merge request that has merge conflicts for a contrib module issue?

Tags: 8

I am trying to reroll a branch called "3226640-link-for-all" for [a contrib issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_glossary/issues/3226640). Note: The intial merge request was created by another user. I am trying to reroll it and maintain the credit to the original user.
What I have tried so far:

I got the branch checked out and gained push access.
I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/creating-issue-forks-and-merge-requests#s-rebasing-a-merge-request) (Exhibit A):
However I have also looked at some [more general instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53066481/1331768).

The commands I used to start the rebase were:

```
    git clone https://git.drupalcode.org/project/search_api_glossary.git
    cd search_api_glossary
    git remote add search_api_glossary-3226640 git@git.drupal.org:issue/search_api_glossary-3226640.git
    git fetch search_api_glossary-3226640
    git checkout -b '3226640-link-for-all' --track search_api_glossary-3226640/'3226640-link-for-all'
    git rebase origin/8.x-4.x -i
```

I marked the single commit by the other author as "Pick"

Then I resolved the one conflict (upstream changes to the same line) and did a:

```
git add -A && git rebase --continue
```

This seems pretty good and I now have a branch that contains the upstream commits plus a single commit (attributed to the original author) that contains both the upstream changes to the line in question and the branch changes.

Now the guide(A) says to do a git push origin.
However there are problems with that and I am pretty sure I should be doing git push {{issue_branch}} instead which in this case is

```
git push search_api_glossary-3226640 3226640-link-for-all
```

Am I correct in that assumption?

If so then the next issue is that my local branch has diverged from the origin and shows as 4 ahead and 1 behind. Therefore it won't push. I am guessing this is due to my choice of "Pick" in the interactive rebase. What should I have chosen there?